# failed to parse date on unmarshalling

Tags: go

I'm trying to unmarshall a json that has a timestamp field, but I'm getting errors in the marshalling, I tried to create a customizable unmarshall but without success.

json:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-08-30T04:03:31.3313066"
}
```

custom time struct:

```
type eventTime struct {
    timeStamp time.Time
}

func (m *eventTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Ignore null, like in the main JSON package.
    if string(data) == "null" || string(data) == `""` {
        return nil
    }
    // Fractional seconds are handled implicitly by Parse.
    tt, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05", string(data))
    *m = eventTime{tt}
    return err
}
```

error:

```
error(*time.ParseError) *{Layout: "2006-01-02T15:04:05", Value: "\"2023-08-30T04:03:31.3313066\"", LayoutElem: "2006", ValueElem: "\"2023-08-30T04:03:31.3313066\"", Message: ""}
```

Comment: You need to remove the surrounding double quotes from the `data`, or include them in the _layout_ argument. https://go.dev/play/p/rmKnTVibtr9

Comment: Print out the exact data you are getting in `UnmarshalJSON`. The error shows you have only a quoted string, so you would need to strip the quotes (or add those to the time format), but your code suggests you are getting the json for the entire structure.

Comment: If you have any say in the time format in the JSON data, just you can just get it formatted to RFC 3339, in which case the time package just takes care of things itself (`time` implements its own `MarshalJSON` and `UnsmarshalJSON`).  If not, your input format clearly doesn't match the given format (You're providing `Y-m-dTH:i:s`, whereas the data is `Y-m-dTH:i:s.u`

Answer (score 0):

You do need to take into account the quotes in your data.

Here is code that works after adding the double quotes to your format:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    data := `{"timestamp": "2023-08-30T04:03:31.3313066"}`

    e := MyStuff{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &e)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", e.Timestamp.timeStamp)
}

type MyStuff struct {
    Timestamp eventTime
}

type eventTime struct {
    timeStamp time.Time
}

func (m *eventTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Ignore null, like in the main JSON package.
    if string(data) == "null" || string(data) == `""` {
        return nil
    }
    // Fractional seconds are handled implicitly by Parse.
    tt, err := time.Parse(`"2006-01-02T15:04:05"`, string(data))
    *m = eventTime{tt}
    return err
}
```